# Android Wear: How to integrate in existing "older App" (minSDK 2.3)

Tags: android, eclipse, migration

I works in an App that uses min sdk 2.3 and with the old structure (Eclipse style) without Gradle and with ActionBar Sherlock and 3 project dependencies.
Any tutorial or link to migrate that? because next, we need to add a Wear module .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the minimum SDK of wear is 20 (android 4.4) so you can't do it without changing the minimum SDK!